# call contact form on phtml page

Tags: magento-2.1, phtml, contact-form

I called contact form in my .phmtl page using this code:

```
<?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Contact::form.phtml')) ?>
```

The problem is when I click on submit, there's no success message and we don't receive the mail by consequence.

PS:when I try mywebsite.com/contact it works correctly

Comment: when I try mywebsite.com/contact it works correctly

Comment: what do you mean exactly please!

Comment: Hey, check the form action @Nouarizineb

Comment: <form class="form contact"
      action="<?php echo $block->getFormAction(); ?>"
      id="contact-form"
      method="post"
      data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>"
      data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>

Comment: <?php echo $block->getFormAction();die; ?> and check before form

Comment: Hi, when you call contact block in a custom phtml. it will show you the success message on the form action page only. If you want to show the success message on desired page then you will have to do the custom code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please can U try this way to call `form.phtml` in your phtml file.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm")->setTemplate("Magento_Contact::form.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

hope this helpful

Comment: Thank you! it works perfectly

Comment: Ok Thanks .....

Answer (score 1):

Use Below code direct into phtml file

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Magento_Contact::form.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! it works perfectly

Comment: Thank you @Nouarizineb .